# Leiningen Bug In Producing Uberjars Or Misunderstanding?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

What can cause `lein uberjar` to fail with "*Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException*" errors when `lein run` runs my app successfully? I'm using leiningen 2.5.1.

It looks like leiningen provides profiles as a way to make custom environments for certain tasks. However, I don't believe a profile difference between what is happening with `lein run` and `lein uberjar` is responsible because ...

1) I tried producing the uberjar with every possible profile, via `lein with-profile <profile>` for every `<profile>` named in the output of `lein show-profiles`.

2) I ran `lein with-profile uberjar run`, and no errors arose.

In case the answer to this problem and similar problems might be specific to the classes and dependencies involved, it is classes related to Overtone that produce the ClassNoteFoundException errors.

My project.clj file looks like:

```
(defproject cochlea "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "An interactive ear training GUI application"
  :url "http://github.com/seewalker/cochlea"
  :license {:name "GPL v3"
            :url "http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html"}
  :repositories {"conjars" "http://conjars.org/repo"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
             [overtone "0.9.1"]
             [org.clojure/tools.trace "0.7.5"]
             [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.7"]
             [postgresql "9.1-901.jdbc4"]
             [environ "0.5.0"]
             [incanter "1.9.0"]
             [clj-time "0.9.0"]
             [me.raynes/conch "0.8.0"]
             [seesaw "1.4.2" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]]]
  :profiles { :uberjar  {:aot :all} }
  :repl-options { :timeout 120000}
  :main cochlea.core
  :target-path "target/%s")
```